# Ordenar una imagen usando los algoritmos de ordenamiento

Tags: java

```
public class Ordenador {
    public int[] quickSort(int[] arreglo, int ladoIzquierdo, int ladoDerecho){

        int pivote = arreglo[ladoIzquierdo];
        int i = ladoIzquierdo;
        int j = ladoDerecho;
        int variableAux;

        while (i < j) {
            while (arreglo[i] <= pivote && i < j) {
                i++;
            }
            while (arreglo[j] > pivote) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i < j) {
                variableAux = arreglo[i];
                arreglo[i] = arreglo[j];
                arreglo[j] = variableAux;
            }
        }
        arreglo[ladoIzquierdo] = arreglo[j];
        arreglo[j] = pivote;

        if (ladoIzquierdo < j - 1) {
            quickSort(arreglo, ladoIzquierdo, j - 1);
        }
        if (j + 1 < ladoDerecho) {
            quickSort(arreglo, j + 1, ladoDerecho);
        }

        return arreglo;
        }


    public static void mezclar(int arreglo[],int elementoIzquierdo, int elementoMedio, int elementoDerecho){
        int i, j, k;
        int [] arregloTemporal = new int[arreglo.length]; //array auxiliar

        for (i = elementoIzquierdo; i <= elementoDerecho; i++) //copia ambas mitades en el array auxiliar
            arregloTemporal[i] = arreglo[i];

           i = elementoIzquierdo; 
           j = elementoMedio + 1; 
           k = elementoIzquierdo;

           while (i <= elementoMedio && j <= elementoDerecho) //copia el siguiente elemento más grande
               if (arregloTemporal[i] <= arregloTemporal[j])
                   arreglo[k++] = arregloTemporal[i++];
               else
                   arreglo[k++] = arregloTemporal[j++];
           while (i <= elementoMedio) //copia los elementos que quedan de la
               arreglo[k++] = arregloTemporal[i++]; //primera mitad (si los hay)
    }

    public int[] mergeSort(int arreglo[],int elementoIzquierdo, int elementoDerecho){
        if (elementoIzquierdo < elementoDerecho){
            int elementoMedio =(elementoIzquierdo + elementoDerecho)/2;

            mergeSort(arreglo, elementoIzquierdo, elementoMedio);
            mergeSort(arreglo, elementoMedio + 1, elementoDerecho);

            mezclar(arreglo, elementoIzquierdo, elementoMedio, elementoDerecho);
        }
        return arreglo;
    }

    public int[] burbuja(int[] arreglo){
        for(int i = 0; i < arreglo.length - 1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < arreglo.length - 1; j++) {
                if (arreglo[j] < arreglo[j + 1]) {
                    int arregloTemporal = arreglo[j+1];
                    arreglo[j+1] = arreglo[j];
                    arreglo[j] = arregloTemporal;
                }
            }
        }
        return arreglo;
    }
public static void intercambio (int a[], int numero){
        int i1=0;
        int i2;
        int auxiliar;
    while (i1 <= numero-2){
        i2=i1+1;
    while (i2 <= numero-1){
        if(a[i2] < a[i1]){
        auxiliar=a[i2];
        a[i2]=a[i1];
        a[i1]=auxiliar;
}
        i2++;
}
        i1++;
}
        i1=0;
} 
      } 
public static void insercionDirecta(int A[]){
    int p, j;
    int aux;
    for (p = 1; p < A.length; p++){ 
              aux = A[p]; 
              j = p - 1; 
              while ((j >= 0) && (aux < A[j])){ 

                             A[j + 1] = A[j];       
                             j--;                 
              }
              A[j + 1] = aux; 
    }
}
public static void seleccion(int A[]) {
          int i, j, menor, pos, tmp;
          for (i = 0; i < A.length - 1; i++) { 
                menor = A[i]; 
                pos = i; 
                for (j = i + 1; j < A.length; j++){ 
                      if (A[j] < menor) { 
                          menor = A[j]; 
                          pos = j;
                      }
                }
                if (pos != i){ 
                    tmp = A[i];
                    A[i] = A[pos];
                    A[pos] = tmp;
                }
          }
```

- Determinar qué algoritmo de ordenamiento se utilizará. Esto puede ser mediante un menú presentado al usuario para leer su elección.
- Leer una imagen desde un archivo.
- Desordenar la imagen leída y presentarla al usuario.
- Ordenar la imagen mediante el algoritmo seleccionado. Mientras esta se va ordenando mostrar el resultado parcial.
- un orden a cada pixel
- No presentar los resultados parciales con cada movimiento, presentarlos cada cientos o miles de movimientos. Ejemplo: exchange sort 1500000 hará que se muestre la imagen cada 1500000 iteraciones.

Hola, espero puedan ayudarme, se los agradeceria mucho. Tengo que crear un menú donde se imprima el algoritmo que el usuario escoja y a partir de ahí dar un orden a la imagen usando el algoritmo que se escogió, por supuesto dependiendo del algoritmo que se escogió será la velocidad con la que se ordene dado que algunos algoritmos realizan más operaciones que otros

[image: Imagen desordenada]
[image: Orden parcial]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? ¿Qué problema tienes con el código que nos compartes? Puedes seguir el consejo de @the-breaker y revisar cómo hacer una buena pregunta; así garantizas respuestas oportunas y útiles.